# Groovy's java.util.Date or Java's java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, groovy

I have a Java application that is running embedded groovy scripts using a `GroovyClassLoader`. Everything is working great until I hit an odd error while passing Java types to a Groovy script.

My issue is thus: I am passing a `java.util.Date` as a parameter into a groovy script. I found that Groovy's java.util.Date has a fantastic [clearTime()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#clearTime%28%29) function. However when I try to call this function i get this exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.clearTime() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I assume this because I have a Java Date and not a Groovy Date. Is there a way to convert between the two.

I do admit I don't fully understand how Groovy seems to be overriding jdk types. (So much so I don't even know if this is the correct terminology to use here.) Please correct me if I am completely wrong about what happens when you create a java.util.Date inside of Groovy vs. when you pass one in to a function from Java.

Comment: Also, in this case I am considering scrapping passing java dates around and switching to Joda. However I would like to know what in the world Groovy is doing when Java types are passed to it. I am sure I will run to this problem again sooner or later.

Comment: I am not going to bother submitting this as an answer, but my hack-and-slash fix for this is to use the Java GregorianCalendar and use its set() to set the date into it then blank out all the fields I don't like.

Comment: Can you post an example of this failing? There is no "Groovy date"as such, it's a regular date with a metaclass that is looked up by groovy whilst executing your groovy code.

Comment: Even when not messing around with a passed in Date I get the error above. This code fails the same way: `def date = new Date().clearTime();`

Comment: Aha, the line above does work fine when I run it from a stand-alone groovy script or from the groovy command line. So the issue seems to be because I am embedding groovy.

Comment: So long as it is being executed by groovy, it should work... Hence my request for a minimal failing example...

Comment: Yeah i was trying to create a quick fail-case when I realized it only fails when running inside of Java. Creating a failing example will take quite a bit of time since my test case is part of my application. I will work something up tomorrow.

Comment: Also, does using `GroovyClassLoader` to compile the groovy into a java class count as "being executed by groovy?" If not, then this answers my question adequately.

Comment: It should work fine...I'll have a go when I get back to a computer

Comment: I wrote a quick embedded groovy test program and it worked as expected, with Groovy's java.util.Date.clearTime() running correctly with a date passed in from the parent Java program. I will need to look more closely at my actual application to see what it is that is causing this to fail.

Comment: Ok I found out my malfunction here. My test app was bound to groovy 1.8.6 as desired, but my main program was using 1.6.5 (the function I happened to be trying to call was introduced in 1.6.7). Eclipse decided not to run with the new version when I updated my pom.xml.

Comment: Is it all working as expected now?

Comment: Yep I am good now. It was all classpath errors. Problem Existed Between Leopard and Chair.

Comment: can you please post your solution as answer or delete your question? This will remove this question form the list of unanswered ones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out my malfunction here. My test app was bound to groovy 1.8.6 as desired, but my main program was using 1.6.5 (the function I happened to be trying to call was introduced in 1.6.7). Eclipse decided not to run with the new version when I updated my pom.xml.