# Convert time in milliseconds to date format (YYYY-MM-DD) in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Is there a function to convert time in milliseconds to date format (YYYY-MM-DD) in Groovy?

I have a Groovy script which needs to compare to date values as follows:

```
for(i in order_lineitems) 
{
   if(i.startDate==order_submit_date)
   {
        matchedIds1 += i.salesOrderLineitemId+','; 
   }
}
```

Here *i.startDate* has **time in milliseconds** of the date format `yyyy-mm-dd` whereas *order_submit_date* has the **time in milliseconds** in the date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. I need to convert `order_submit_date` into this format `yyyy-mm-dd` within the `if` block itself.

I am new to the Groovy script and I need help here.

There was a small mistake in my code. I corrected it.
The if block should be as follows `if (i.startDate == order_submit_date)` and both are long values represented in millis.

Now I need to make sure the condition is right i.e. start date is equal to order submit date.

Here what is happening is :
i.startDate has the value 1452105000000  (Thu Jan 07 2016 00:00:00) which is been stored in the DB when a Sales Order is created 
and order_submit_date has the value 1452158393097  (Thu Jan 07 2016 14:49:53) which is being genertaed on the flow when a user submits the Sales order for approvals in the UI.
Now since order_sbmit_date has both date and time the long value is different and am unable to satisfy the condition.

Hence now i have a question as to wether there a function ***in groovy*** which would convert my order_submit_date long value to Date(yyyy-mm-dd) format and then compare both the values so as to satisfy the if block.

Comment: What are the types of `i.startDate` & `order_submit_date`?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Sorry for the unclear question.
I have updated my question. Please refer it.

Both the fields have long values.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your dates in millis like this:

Notice that solutions depend on timezone.

Groovy option:

```
def compare(def m1, def m2) {
  def dateInMillis1 = new Date(m1)
  def dateInMillis2 = new Date(m2)
  dateInMillis1.clearTime() == dateInMillis2.clearTime()
}
```

Java option 1:

```
boolean compare1(long millis1, long millis2) {
    Date dateFromMillis = new Date(millis1);
    Date dateFromMillis2 = new Date(millis2);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    sdf.format(dateFromMillis).equals(sdf.format(dateFromMillis2));
}
```

or you can use Calendar:

Java option 2:

```
boolean compare2(long m1, long m2) {
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTimeInMillis(m1);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(m2);
    return calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
            calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&
            calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are type for `i.startDate` and `order_submit_date` java.util.Date? or String?
And do you want use `i.startDate` and `order_submit_date` only to do compare?

-- updated --

ok, then maybe like folowing?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String startDate = "2016-01-20"
String order_submit_date = "2016-01-20 12:34:56"

SimpleDateFormat formatDateWithTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

if (formatDate.parse(startDate) >= formatDateWithTime.parse(order_submit_date)) {
    println "hehe"
} else {
    println "hoho"
}
```

`SimpleDateFormat#parse()` returns `java.util.Date`.
Also you can compare with these.

You can also write like follows!

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
SimpleDateFormat formatDateWithTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

def matchedIds1 = order_lineitems.findAll {
    formatDate.parse(it.startDate) >= formatDateWithTime.parse(order_submit_date)
}.join(",")
```

**Long(type) version**

```
def matchedIds1 = order_lineitems.findAll {
   new Date(it.startDate).clearTime() == new Date(order_submit_date).clearTime()
}.join(",")
```

**Long(type) without clearTime version**

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00"
SimpleDateFormat fillByZero = new SimpleDateFormat(format)

def matchedIds1 = order_lineitems.findAll {
   Date a = new Date(it.startDate)
   Date b = new Date(order_submit_date)
   fillByZero.parse(a.format(format)) == fillByZero.parse(b.format(format))
}.join(",")
```

Comment: The return type is String.
And yes i want to use i.startDate and order_submit_date only to compare here.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.
I have updated my question. Please refer it.

Both the fields have long values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have been getting this error when am using the clearTime() function: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:No signature of method: java.util.Date.clearTime() is applicable for argument types: () values: {}

Comment: How do you use "clearTime()" ?
Can you show the code me? (and JDK, Groovy's version too)

Comment: Hi @Koji,
I figured out the error. 
My code base was using an older version of groovy and it was not supporting the .clearTime() function.

Comment: @NitinVegi i added "Long(type) without clearTime version".  Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear that whether your dates are in string format or in milliseconds (long).

**If dates are in string format like "2015-10-31"**

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
...


SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

for (i in order_lineitems) {
   if (dateParser.parse(i.startDate) >= dateTimeParser.parse(order_submit_date)) {
        matchedIds1 += i.salesOrderLineitemId+','; 
   }
}
```

**If dates are in milliseconds:**

```
for (i in order_lineitems) {
   if (new Date(i.startDate.toString().toLong()) >= new Date(order_submit_date.toString().toLong())) {
        matchedIds1 += i.salesOrderLineitemId+','; 
   }
}
```

*Note*: Capital `Y` and small `y` (similarly for `m` & `h`) matterns in terms of formatting so please be clear about the usage.

## Actual Answer to the Question:

You don't need any of the above solution instead you can simply use the [clearTime()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#clearTime()) method on the date like below:

```
for (i in order_lineitems) {
   if (new Date(i.startDate) >= new Date(order_submit_date).clearTime()) {
        matchedIds1 += i.salesOrderLineitemId+','; 
   }
}
```

The `clearTime()` method will simply remove the time part from your date i.e. will convert `Thu Jan 07 2016 14:49:53` to Thu Jan 07 2016 00:00:00`

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.
I have updated my question. Please refer it.

Both the fields have long values.

Comment: Another question here for the **Actual Answer**.
Since my values are in long. Would the clearTime() function remove the time part from the long value ?
And thanks for the answer @ShashankAgarwal

Comment: Yes, that long value is actually the EPOCH time i.e. number of milliseconds from **Thursday, 1 January 1970** so doing will `clearTime()` will reset the time for that day to `00:00:00` and hence time part will be removed. Read the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime() &  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: I have been getting this error when am using the clearTime() function: 
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:No signature of method: java.util.Date.clearTime() is applicable for argument types: () values: {}`

Comment: There's already a question posted on this forum, but am unable to figure out a way to clear the error.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792824/groovys-java-util-date-or-javas-java-util-date